# Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, sqlsrv

i wish to fire select query for login on user table .
i am using php and ms msql server 2005 as backend

my php code is correct but my database is on other p.c in network.
i need to know is there any configuration setting needed to be done. i am using xampp V 1.8.3      including php 5.5.1

Comment: Did you download & install SQLSRV ?

Comment: yes i have downloaded sqlsrv30 and copied all files to php folder.

Comment: did you change the php.ini as well ?

Comment: actually not getting sql server native client (snac) 64 bit v and not understanding what change to make in php.inf .....plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install SQLSRV 3.0 to Apache (I assume) in Windows platform, here are the steps:

1. Put the driver file in your PHP extension directory.
2. Modify the php.ini file to include the driver. For example: `extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll`
3. Restart Apache

Then, verify the installation using `phpinfo()`.

Reference: [TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1258.accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx)

Comment: Tried this on my Xampp installation. The DLL you've named here does not exists in the package. I've tried this one: php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll but it says "Unable to load dynamic library"