# Microsoft SQLSRV PHP 5.5

Tags: php, sql-server

I have installed WAMP 32 bits version and PHP 5.5. I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database. I am using this driver https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx, which I extracted it in the /ext folder. Then, I changed my .ini file writing "extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll".

However, it still does not work. The error message is: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() and in the phpinfo() page does not appear information about SQLSERVER

Comment: After putting that library into the extensions folder you also have to load it. PHP offers the `extions=` command for that. You will find existing examples in your installation for other extensions. After adding it you have to restart php, so most likely the http server you use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function sqlsrv\_connect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563146/call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect)

Comment: I did it also the extensions= adding (writing it in the php.ini)

Answer (score 0):

in windows, inside your project directory, run php --ini. It will tell you which php.ini you should put your php_sqlsrv.dll file